# SQLite android NullPointerException when inserting on sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I know that similar questions exists, but all I found relates to not having an instance of `SQLiteDatabase`.

One of the table definitions in my `onCreate` method which creates a database looks like that:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE offers(" +
            "    game_state_id   INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES game_states (id)," +
            "    city_id         INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES cities (id)," +
            "    item_id         INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES items (id)," +
            "    sell_price      INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "    buy_price       INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "    amount          INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "    UNIQUE (game_state_id, city_id, item_id)" +
            ")");
```

And it's working, the database looks fine.

```
public long createGameState() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", "default");
    values.put("current_city_id", getInitialCityId());
    // it could return -1 if insert didn't work
    long res = db.insert("game_states", null, values);

    List<City> cities = loadCities();
    List<Item> items = loadItems();
    Log.d("Kupiec", "Itemki: "+String.valueOf(items.size())+" | Miasta: "+String.valueOf(cities.size()));

    for (City city : cities) {
        for (Item item : items) {
            ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
            values2.put("item_id", item.id);
            values2.put("city_id", city.id);
            values2.put("game_state_id", res);
            values2.put("buy_price", Utils.getRandom(100, 125));
            values2.put("sell_price", Utils.getRandom(75, 100));
            values2.put("amount", Utils.getRandom(15, 30));
            Log.d("Kupiec", "offer_values: "+values2.toString());
            db.insert("offers", null, values2);
        }
    }

    db.close();
    return res;
}
```

What's interesting, the first insert, into the `game_states` table is working fine, however it breaks on the first insert in the loop.

```
06-12 13:28:03.872      630-630/com.mippit.kupiec E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:290)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:115)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
    at com.mippit.kupiec.Repository.createGameState(Repository.java:182)
    at com.mippit.kupiec.Repository.createNewGame(Repository.java:153)
    at com.mippit.kupiec.MainActivity.clicked_new_game(MainActivity.java:42)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's going on? Line 182 with this error is the line with `db.insert("offers", null, values2);`

I got the good answer, however the author removed it, probably because he got 2 downvotes (not from me!). **If someone from the stuff can return it back, please do it, I would be glad to mark it as accepted.**

The correct answer was, at last, to `try {...} catch {}` this `NullPointerException` and load the database once again. I don't understand why it's happening, because I thought that db will be open until I explicitly say `db.close()`, however, it's working.

Comment: You are giving 'db.insert()' a 'values2' object. This looks pretty much empty to me.

Comment: I changed it, and it still returns the same error.

Comment: make sure your table is created at run time..

Comment: It is created, I don't remove it, because the table looks fine to me.

Comment: have you checked if there is something wrong in `loadCities();` or `loadItems();` if a null returned in there inside their variables

Comment: I'm assuming when you log `values2`, everything shows up?  If that is the case, then `db` must be null.

Comment: I got the right answer, but someone removed it. However I still don't understand how db can suddenly become null after doing one insertion to `game_states` fine?

Comment: Kernel decides when to close db, you really don't even need to call close when working directly with a SQLite db.

Comment: Ok, but it's still weird for me to close my database inside a function. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seen that the problem is you already inserted values in database with different table and without closing it you are trying to insert again. so conflict is there. replace your for loop statement

```
db.insert("offers", null, values2);
```

with

```
db.insertWithOnConflict("table name", null, "values", SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved a problem, but I didn't know why it is happening. Good to know!

Comment: i already mention in explanation that u are trying to insert into already open database. close database after first insertion.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `game_state_id` is required to be unique.  You keep assigning it the same value, `res`, which you got from above.  So, it will work the first time, but not any other time...

Comment: It don't work even at the first time, my "offers" table is still empty.

Moreover, if I understand SQL well, `UNIQUE (game_state_id, city_id, item_id)` is saying, that this tuple has to be unique, not only the `game_state_id`.

Comment: To be sure, I tried to remove the uniqueness constraint, and as I thought, it didn't help.